# Working with Password_hash and password_verify

Tags: password-encryption, password-hash

I'm new to `password_hash` and `password_verify`, and they appear to be the most efficient way of storing passwords securely!

I noticed that `password_hash` produces different hash for the same `plain-text` value `every time`!

This means that if a user tried to create an account with the password `(thisIsMyPassword)` it will generate a hash like this `$2y$10$VCNH8ndve8hwbvLJ2nMHtOsEiigE4zA7ViADxCJfq9bmUCmkNkcce`,

And if another or the same user tried to create another account with the same password i.e. `(thisIsMyPassword)` the account will be created and the hash value of the password will be something like `$2y$10$Hqssc5nn3pzgfwqVwQrQz.Ny71q972RXmCmyV9ykywG8iELbsf47a`!

Now you see the same value i.e. `(thisIsMyPassword)` resulted in different hashes!

Is this OK?

Is it OK to let the users use same passwords, as long as the password hash is different in the database?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `password_hash`, but the fact that you are getting different results for the same input suggest that you are **NOT** using real hashing. Real hashing will **ALWAYS** return the same hash for the same input.

Comment: I don't know if you used the php function `password_hash` before, but this function returns different hashes for the same plain-text value ( that's the point of it)! And clearly you didn't understand my question very well!

Comment: No, I never used PHP, but used hashing in a looooong list of applications, and it **always** returned the same value for the same input. You may consider other option, **tokenization** (though I doubt it is supported in PHP.

Comment: Its intended, because password_hash generate a random salt before hashing the password. Hence for the same password, it will always have different hash.

Comment: @FDavidov that's not true. This is "real" hashing, but it includes a random salt to force the same input to produce different output. If you hold the salt constant, the same input will produce the same output (this is how verify works). This is a desired security property. Salting helps resist both rainbow tables, as well as brute force attacks by making the attacker limit their search to a single hash at a time (since each salt is different, they must re-try their attack on each unique salt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The password hash includes a so-called *salt*, a small random value, which is here to prevent dictionary attacks, here is what PHP manual says:

> If omitted, a random salt will be generated by password_hash() 
>   for each password hashed. This is the intended mode of operation.

The value you get as the output, is not really a plain hash, but a 
string made of - *algorithm id*, *salt* and HASH(*password*,*salt*).

> The used algorithm, cost and salt are returned as part of the hash.
>   Therefore, all information that's needed to verify the hash is included. 
>   in it. This allows the password_verify() function to verify the hash
>   without needing separate storage for the salt or algorithm information.

Comment: OK I understand, but when it comes to storing the password in the database. Should I check to see if the password already exists or just leave the users use an already used password knowing that the hash is different?

Comment: There is no direct way, you can check if password is already used, when using a salted hash.

Moreover, an ability to check if the password is already used by some other user account makes a vulnerability on itself, as you can use it to detect that other user account is already using the password you have just tried to set, and once you know that you have a valid password you can then just apply it against all the user accounts until your attack succeeds.

Comment: Thank you so much for  answering my question and thanks to all the other people that tried to help! I just went on Facebook and Twitter to test this. FIRST: I created an account with the password `TESTPASS_1` and the account has been created, and then I created another account with the same password and the account has been created (Facebook and Twitter did not show an error saying the password `TESTPASS_1` is already used or taken!)